# Lost old data after add new data Django Admin

Tags: django

```
class Song(models.Model):
song_id = models.AutoField(default=1,primary_key=True,editable=False)
file = models.FileField(upload_to=only_filename,null=True,blank=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
album_id = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
lyric = models.TextField()
cover_imagemodels.ImageField(upload_to="img/",default="img/None/icon.jpg")
listen_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,editable=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Above is my class model. First, I login to superuser in Django Admin, then add a new song. It's success.
But, after that I continue add another song, there is only a newest song is saved, and older song dispear.
I use mysql command line to check and there is only newest one is exist.
How to fix it?
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Try not to use default in `song_id`. How do you create a song? Show the code.

Comment: I create a new song in Django admin, no using code. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely shouldn't be setting a default in the primary key field, `song_id`. That value is assigned when you instantiate an object, whereas the proper sequence value - which would be set by the database - wouldn't be assigned until the object is saved, by which time it already has a value : 1. So each item is saved with the same primary key.

Just delete that default.